# C: simple code not working as expected (PIC micro)

Tags: c, pic, microchip

This line isn't working as expected:

```
uartPushPos = (uartPushPos + 1) % UART_TX_BUFF_LENGTH;
```

However this below, which in theory does the same, does work:

```
//if (uartPushPos == UART_TX_BUFF_LENGTH - 1){
if (uartPushPos >= UART_TX_BUFF_LENGTH - 1){
    uartPushPos = 0;
} else {
    uartPushPos++;
}
```

UartPopPos is type char, and UART_TX_BUFF_LENGTH  is a preprocessor variable set to 16.

Why does the second code segment work, but not the first?

If it makes much of a difference, I'm using the SourceBoost BoostC compiler for the PIC microcontroller 16f.

Thanks

Comment: In what way are you getting unexpected results with the first option?

Comment: Is there a flag, such as the `-S` flag for gcc, that lets you have a look at the compiled assembler code? I think that would help you.

Comment: All I know is it's not working as expected, I can't get my head round what's actually happening, perhaps I should some how isolate the code segment to test it properly, I was just hoping there was an obvious answer I'd missed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different if `uartPushPos` is less than 0, or if it is more than or equal to `UART_TX_BUFF_LENGTH`.

See also [Mod of negative number is melting my brain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain)

Comment: Also, the second snippet wouldn't work if `uartPushPos > UART_TX_BUFF_LENGTH - 1`.

Comment: @Andre Laszlo: I mentioned that :)

Comment: Haha, sorry. Well, proper initialization is your friend I guess. And reading stuff before you comment...

Comment: I've commented out the if statement for a new one so they should now be equivalent. (It didn't matter though, since the code with the if statement was the working one, not the modulo line). uartPushPos is a char so cannot be negative. There's still a difference some how,

Comment: @Jodes: A char can be negative unless you configure your compiler to treat chars as unsigned (I know several PIC compilers where you can do this). Use `unsigned char` if you only want positive integers.

Comment: The classic solution btw is to first add the bufferlength, and only then do the mod so   (x+bufferlength+1) % bufferlength. Of course this only fixes the case where x >-bufferlength, but usually fixing the case -1 is enough.