# Euclidean integer modulo in C++

Tags: c++, math, integer, division, modulo

Where can I find an implementation or library that computes the remainder of an integer Euclidean division, `0 <= r < |n|`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++98 and C++03 versions of C++ language the built-in division (bit `/` and `%` operators) might be Euclidean and might be non-Euclidean - it is implementation defined. However, most implementations truncate the quotient towards zero, which is unfortunately *non-Euclidean*.

In most implementations `5 / -3 = -1` and `5 % -3 = -2`. In Euclidean division `5 / -3 = -2` and `5 % -3 = 1`.

C++11 requires integer division to be non-Euclidean: it requires an implementation that truncates towards zero.

The issue, as you can see, arises with negative numbers only. So, you can easily implement Euclidean division yourself by using operator `%` and post-correcting negative remainders

```
int euclidean_remainder(int a, int b)
{
  assert(b != 0);
  int r = a % b;
  return r >= 0 ? r : r + std::abs(b);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Try `(x%m + m)%m` if the result must be positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain).

Write your own function around this, or any of the variants, and don't get hung up on a library - you've spent more time asking than you would to just do it.  Start your own library (toolbox) for simple functions you need.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks. Is there no library that implements this function ? It seems fairly common...

Comment: This method is unnecessary slow due to the two `%` operations, which involve integer divisions. It is possible to construct a branchless version of @AnT's answer, which will only use a single `%` operation.

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple operator.  %.

5 % 4 is 1, etc.

Edit:
As has been pointed out, depending on your implementation this isn't necessarily a euclidean mod.

```
#define EUCMOD(a, b)  (a < 0 ? (((a % b) + b) % b) : (a % b))
```

Comment: Note this only works with integers. If you want floating-point modulus, use the `fmod` function. `fmod (3.3, 2.4) is 0.9`

Comment: No, I said an euclidian division. (-5)%4 is -1 but should be 3. As I said in the question, the remainder r should be between 0 and n, and in my example it's negative.

Comment: @NaomiJO, If you really need to, you can just add the `b` from `a % b` onto the result if it's negative.

Comment: That's actually incorrect. In most implementations division truncates the result towards zero - this is non-Euclidean division. This means that the result of `%` can be negative: this is non-Euclidean already.

Comment: This method is unnecessary slow due to the two `%` operations, which involve integer divisions. It is possible to construct a branchless version of @AnT's answer, which will only use a single `%` operation.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Brandon's answer, but I started having some strange bugs.
After some testing I found that the expansion of the EUCMOD macro was messing with the precedence of operations.

So I'd suggest using it as a function instead of a macro

```
int eucmod(const int a, const int b)
{
    return (a < 0 ? (((a % b) + b) % b) : (a % b));
}
```

Or adding a few parenthesis

```
#define EUCMOD(a,b) ((a) < 0 ? ((((a) % (b)) + (b)) % (b)) : ((a) % (b)))
```