# Keep an index within bounds and wrap around

Tags: javascript

I am doing a little carousel with a pager. The carousel displays elements 6 by 6 and I have 36 elements to display. I have a next and previous button. The first elements displayed are [0, 6]. If I press the previous button and there is no previous elements (eg I am on the first page), it should wrap around and go to the end. The same applies for the last elements and the next button.

My code looks like this:

```
$('#img_prev').click(function (e) {
    # change this line so it wraps around
    imgIndex = (imgIndex - 6) % 36;
    alert(imgIndex)
    refreshImages(imgIndex);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
$('#img_next').click(function (e) {
    imgIndex = (imgIndex + 6) % 36;
    refreshImages(imgIndex);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

And it fails miserably because -6 % 36 is -6 and not 30. I could handle it with if `(index < 0) ...` but I would prefer a condition with a modulo that best capture the wrapping behavior.

How can I get this to wrap around (see 2nd line) ?

Comment: _“And it fails miserably because -6 % 36 is -6 and not 30.”_ – well then add another 36 (so `+30` with subtracting 6 in one step already) before doing the modulo division …

Comment: @CBroe Yes actually it is equivalent with what I had in mind (see my answer)

Comment: `imgIndex = ((imgIndex - 6) + 36) % 36;` which is `(imgIndex + 30) % 36` though that's harder to read.

Comment: simpliest workarroud is imgIndex = (36 + imgIndex + 6) % 36;

Answer (score 12):

One possible solution would be with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082938/311744):

```
function mod(x, m) {
    return (x%m + m)%m;
}

$('#img_prev').click(function (e) {
    # this line has been changed, now it wraps around
    imgIndex = mod(imgIndex - 6, 36);
    ...
```

Comment: You don’t need to do modulo with the same “divisor” twice, `return (x + m)%m` should be enough.

Comment: @CBroe The author of the function mod (@ShreevatsaR) must have a good reason for doing that. I was thinking maybe for some edges cases with negative numbers. But I can't figure any were `(x + m)%m` and `(x%m + m)%m` are different. So good point.

Comment: No, you are actually right – if the index we are trying to “contain” here was _very_ out of bounds already (manipulated elsewhere in code or whatever), so for example `-41`, then we would get `(-41+36)%36 = -5` with my proposal – so doing modulo on the input value first does have its eligibility: `(-41%36+36)%36 = 31`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var maxElements = 36;
$('#img_prev').click(function (e) {
    // change this line so it wraps around
    imgIndex = (maxElements - 1) - (imgIndex % maxElements);
    alert(imgIndex)
    refreshImages(imgIndex);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
$('#img_next').click(function (e) {
    imgIndex = (imgIndex % maxElements);
    refreshImages(imgIndex);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUBjR/)** showing the output of:

```
(imgIndex % maxElements)
```

and

```
(maxElements - 1) - (imgIndex % maxElements);
```