# How to simply loop a custom scale

Tags: c++, math

This must be really simple math but I don't know how to solve it.

I need to write a function that returns a number on a scale from 1 to 3 like this:

```
input: -5 output: 1
input: -4 output: 2
input: -3 output: 3
input: -2 output: 1
input: -1 output: 2
input: 0  output: 3
input: 1  output: 1
input: 2  output: 2
input: 3  output: 3
input: 4  output: 1
input: 5  output: 2
input: 6  output: 3
input: 7  output: 1
```

The following function works great with positive numbers

```
static const int getOnScaleOneToThree(int input)
{
    int x = ceil(input / 3);
    return abs((input - (x * 3)));
}
```

But it inverts (of course) with negative input like this:

```
input: -6 output: 3
input: -5 output: 2
input: -4 output: 1
input: -3 output: 3
input: -2 output: 2
input: -1 output: 1
input: 0  output: 3
input: 1  output: 1
input: 2  output: 2
input: 3  output: 3
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to make it as general as possible. Let me know if you can formulate the question to be pure mathematics please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mod of negative number is melting my brain!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain)

Comment: @RobWatts That's C#, though.

Comment: @Aberrant true, but there are answers that cover C++ as well

Comment: @RobWatts I suppose the top answer works for C++ and it's actually more elegant than my answer, as well as all the other answers here. I don't think it would be a good course of action to close this question as a duplicate of that one, though, since either of the languages could change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, and avoids the implementation-dependent outcome of a modulo operation with a negative number.

```
if(input >= 0)
{
    return (1 + ((input + 2) % 3)); 
}
else
{
    return (3 - ((-input) % 3));
}
```

Additionally, here's a more general (and verbose) solution:

```
static const int getOnScale(int input, int minVal, int maxVal, int zeroVal)
{
    if(input == 0)
    {
        //Might as well return this right away.
        return zeroVal;
    }
    else
    {
        if(maxVal >= minVal)
        {
            int divisor = maxVal - minVal + 1;
            if(input > 0)
            {
                int dividend = input + zeroVal - minVal;
                return (minVal + (dividend % divisor));
            }
            else
            {
                int dividend = maxVal - zeroVal - input;
                return (maxVal - (dividend % divisor));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Reverse scale
            int divisor = minVal - zeroVal + 1;
            if(input > 0)
            {
                int dividend = minVal - zeroVal + input;
                return (minVal - (dividend % divisor));
            }
            else
            {
                int dividend = -input + zeroVal - maxVal;
                return (maxVal + (dividend % divisor));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this question's case, this function would be called as:

```
getOnScale(input, 1, 3, 3);
```

Comment: @Daggepagge: I just edited it, it needed to be `input + 2` for the positive numbers, not `input + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LUT (look-up table). Here is some pseudocode:

```
int output[] = { 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
assert(input >= -6 && input <= 3);
int index = input+6;
int value = output[index];
```

LUTs are super-fast, easy to maintain and perfect for strange mappings that are difficult to calculate at runtime.

They pose a challange when the input range is large - memory requirements can obviously reach the stratosphere. There are solutions for that, such as:

1. approximation using linear functions (map range of input to linear function)
2. approximation using polynominals
3. range maps

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int out( int in )
{
    return ( in >= 0 ) ? ( ( in + 2 ) % 3 ) + 1 : 3 - ( -1 * in % 3 ); }
}
```

Good point about the *implementation-defined* behaviour when the *dividend* goes below zero and the *divisor* is positive.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7594577/718379 , the sign of the remainder is _implementation-defined_.

Answer (score 1):

```
static const int getOnScaleOneToThree(int input)
{
    return (int)((unsigned int)(input + 0x80000000)%3 + 1);
}
```

This works if `int` is 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I've been contemplating this for a bit, but based on this:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213976/171816

I'm just going to post this as an extra answer, referencing the answer on that other question.

---

The other answer has a solution more elegant than my first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082938/982107

by writing the modulo function as

```
static int mod(int x, int m)
{
    int r = x%m;
    return r<0 ? r+m : r;
}
```

you will get the right answers for this problem even when x is negative.

This will allow you to write the function like so:

```
static int getOnScaleOneToThree(int input)
{
    return (mod((input + 2), 3) + 1);
}
```

---

Here's a general solution again, this time keeping the amount of code to a minimum:

```
static int getOnScale(int input, int minVal, int maxVal, int zeroVal)
{
    int dividend = input;
    if(minVal > maxVal)
    {
        //Alter values for reverse scale
        std::swap(minVal, maxVal);
        dividend *= -1;
    }
    dividend += (zeroVal - minVal);
    int divisor = maxVal - minVal + 1;
    return (mod(dividend , divisor) + minVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important not to get tangled up in premature optimization, so the following is probably sufficient.

```
long get_remainder(long n) {
    long * remainders = new[(unsigned int)0xffffffff];

    long remainder = 1;
    for ( long i = LONG_MIN; i < LONG_MAX; ++i ) {
        remainders[i + -LONG_MIN] = remainder++;
        if ( remainder > 3 )
            remainder = 1;
    }

    int rtn = remainders[n + -LONG_MIN];

    delete[] remainders;

    return rtn;
}
```

Use like so:

```
for ( int i = -10; i < 10; ++i )
{
    int remainder = get_remainder(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes, premature optimization is bad, but allocating 16GB of memory for each call, is a bit.. extreme, IMO. This will not work on most systems.

Comment: "The greatest danger to good computer science research today may be excessive relevance." -- Dennis M. Ritchie. If you want to discuss the arbitrary restrictions imposed by particular platforms, that conversation might be better suited to a system administration forum.