# How can I get the modulus in C#?

Tags: c#, modulus

TL;DR:

```
int remainder = -1 % 5; //-1
int modulus = -1 modulus 5; //4 How do I do this?
```

---

I am trying to read the modulated value of an array.  So the index modulated by the array length would be the updated index.  For example:

```
array = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}
array[6] = array[6 mod 5] = array[1] = 200
```

Easy enough.  But when my index is negative, that's where I get into trouble.

```
array[-1] = array[???] = array[4] = 500
```

I do not know how to perform -1 mod 5.  The remainder operator works for positives, but not negatives.

Here is my sample code that only works for positive values:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = new int[5] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
    int myIndex = myArray.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        myIndex = --myIndex % myArray.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + myArray[myIndex]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

How can I get the modulus of a number, not the remainder in C#?

Comment: Actually, the remainder operator *does* work for negatives, The remainder of dividing -1 by 5 is -1, simply because `-1/5` is 0, and `-1` is the difference between `0*5` and `-1`. The problem is that you want something else than what this operator provides.

Comment: The simplest way would be to do a double remainder calculation: `a % b` --> `((a % b) + b) % b`.

Comment: See [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082938/580951).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is this:

```
var newIndex = myIndex % myArray.Length;
if (newIndex < 0) 
{
    newIndex += myArray.Length;
}
```

Does it do what you want?

I am also confused by your usage of 'modulus'. As far as I know, modulus is an absolute value. In order to get it, simply use

```
var modulus = Math.Abs(value)
```

Comment: Errr, yes.  That is what I use.  I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  I suspected that C# would have some sort of modulus operator, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @edit: The modulus is not the absolute value.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13683709/1889720