# Find/simplify overlapping modulo

Tags: c#, modulo, simplify, integer-division

I have some code solving today's "Advent of code part 2". https://adventofcode.com/

I have currently many hardcoded modulo conditions, is there any simple way to reduce the number of conditions?

Since in general you can skip checking `x % 4 == 0` if you already checked `x % 2 == 0`. But I have a hard time figuring out how to simplify when there is addition involved. Any suggestions or resources I can look up?

```
if (delay % 6 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay +1) % 2 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay +2) % 4 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 4) % 6 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 6) % 14 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 8) % 8 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 10) % 14 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 12) % 10 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 14) % 10 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 16) % 14 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 18) % 10 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 20) % 10 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 22) % 22 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 24) % 22 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 26) % 18 == 0)
{
    return false;
} 

if ((delay + 28) % 14 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 32) % 14 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 36) % 16 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 40) % 14 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 44) % 32 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 50) % 18 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 56) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 58) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 60) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 62) % 22 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 64) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 66) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 68) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 70) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 74) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 76) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
if ((delay + 80) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

if ((delay + 88) % 26 == 0)
{
    return false;
}

doSomeComputation...
```

Comment: what is the question exactly, check if the number is divisible?

Comment: You can *not* skip `x % 4 == 0` when passing `x % 2 == 0`.

Comment: @Sefe I believe what the OP means is that if you test `x % 2 == 0` and return then there's no need to test `x % 4 == 0` after that because anything divisible by 4 is also divisible by 2.

Comment: @juharr But that's what he's already doing. Dropping the second test (which is actually not in the actual code provided) will change the semantics of the code. And that's what he clearly doesn't want.

Comment: @juharr, exactly, and that was only an example since i don't understand how to do it when there is a '+' involved. Question is are there any redundant checks, and if there are how can it find them?

Comment: Would you mind providing the exact link to the challenge you are coding?

Comment: @dumetrulo: not sure if part 2 is available if you havn't solved part 1, but here goes: https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/13

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `delay` is always nonnegative. If that is not guaranteed by your inputs, you can replace  the modulus call with a version that fixes it, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082938/1992137). That said, the logic you posted could be replicated with this:

```
const int lcm = 1441440;
int[] residues = new int[]
{
    1924,
    92644,
    132964,
    223684,
    354724,
    395044,
    616804,
    657124,
    788164,
    878884,
    1009924,
    1050244,
    1181284,
    1272004,
    1312324,
    1403044
};
if (!residues.Contains(delay % lcm)) return false;
```

Explanation of how to generate it: `lcm` is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the numbers you are modding by. You can get that by asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) or any number of other ways. The constant residues can be obtained by simply iterating over all the residues mod `lcm` and checking which ones pass the logic as you have it written already. The following code is what I used to print them out, where the function `myPass` is just the logic that you provided above.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1441440; ++i)
   if (myPass(i))
       Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", i);
```

Explanation of why it works: If `delay` is an integer and `m` is a positive integer and `n` is a positive integer that is divisible by `m`, then the value of `delay % m` is equal to `(delay % n) % m`. An example: suppose an integer `delay` has `delay % lcm == 1924`. Then we have that `delay % 6` is equal to `(delay % lcm) % 6` which is `1924 % 6` which is `4`. Similarly, as long as `delay % lcm` is a value `i` in the hard-coded list of residues which we tested to match all of the various conditions in your `if`s, then we know that `delay` matches them, too, because--for whatever `m` a particular `if` was testing against--we generated our list in such a way that we already know that `i % m` matches the condition, and now we have that `(delay % m) == (delay % lcm) % m) == i % m`.

Note: this approach is only feasible because your set of conditions excludes many residues of only small moduli. If there were, for example, one outlying condition comparing against a large prime, the list of residues could easily become too large to handle.