# Circulating integer

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, int, modulo

I need to write an integer that "circulates" between a minimum and maximum value. If the maximum value is reached and you add 1, it jumps to the minimum value. If you subtract 1 from the minimum value you reach the maxValue.

---

Example:
minValue = 2;
maxValue = 10;

leads to:  ... 2,3,4,...9,10,2,3,...

---

I figured out the addition algorithm, but I'm stuck with the subtraction.
Addition looks like this:

```
public static circularInt operator +(circularInt a, int b)
{
    int sum = a.value + b;        
    int circularValue = ((sum - a.minValue) % (a.maxValue + 1 - a.minValue)) + a.minValue;

    return new circularInt(circularValue, a.minValue, a.maxValue);
}
```

Basically the algorithm can be broken down to "newValue % range". All the +- minValue is just to eliminate it from the calculation, and add it later on again.

Is there a known algorithm for this? If not, do you have an idea how the subtraction algorithm might look like?

Comment: One thing you should remember, that int also has limits, so if resulting addition/subtraction will overflow(you an play with "range" like (int.MaxValue - 10, int.MaxValue), for example), you algorithm can run into problems.

Comment: Sure, in this case the min/max value will be far away from int.MaxValue. :)

Comment: It was not specified in the task)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by applying the modulo to `b` and subtracting the minimum from `a.value`

```
int range = a.maxValue + 1 - a.minValue;
b %= range;
int value = a.value - a.minValue;
```

Allowing for negative values, `b` will now be greater than `-range` and less than `range`.

For addition, add `b` and the `range` to the `value`, and apply the modulo. Adding the `range` is necessary when `b` is a negative number. Adding a negative number is the same as subtracting a positive number.

```
int result = (value+range+b) % range;
```

For subtraction, add the `range` to the `value` before subtracting `b`, and apply the modulo. This works because `(value+range) % range == value` so adding the range doesn't change the final result, but it does keep the intermediate result from going negative.

```
int result = (value+range-b) % range;
```

Finish by adding the minimum back in

```
int circularValue = result + a.minValue;
```

---

Here's the final code, courtesy of [@Meister der Magie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13174465/meister-der-magie)

Addition:

```
public static circularInt operator +(circularInt a, int b)
{
    int range = (a.maxValue + 1 - a.minValue);
    b %= range;
    int value = a.value - a.minValue;

    int additionResult = (value+range+b) % range;

    int circularValue = additionResult + a.minValue;
    return new circularInt(circularValue, a.minValue, a.maxValue);
}
```

Subtraction:

```
public static circularInt operator -(circularInt a, int b)
{
    int range = (a.maxValue + 1 - a.minValue);
    b %= range;
    int value = a.value - a.minValue;

    int subtractionResult = (value+range-b) % range;

    int circularValue = subtractionResult + a.minValue;
    return new circularInt(circularValue, a.minValue, a.maxValue);
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @MeisterderMagie Any time, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
int sum = a.value + b;
```

with

```
int sum = (a.value - b + ( (b / range) * range) );
```

where

```
int range = a.maxValue + 1 - a.minValue;
```

should work fine!

Comment: Nope, that's what I thought at first. But it doesn't return values between minValue and maxValue.

Comment: though it wont return values between minvalue and maxvalue, after doing % (a.maxValue + 1 - a.minValue), it will be in the range. pls check

Comment: @nikhilbalwani [mod of negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea for the formula:

```
private const int MinValue = 2;
private const int MaxValue = 10;

public static int AddCircular(int a, int b)
{
    int modulo = MaxValue - MinValue + 1;
    int sum = (a - MinValue + b) % modulo + MinValue;
    if (sum < MinValue) sum += modulo;
    return sum;
}
```

Output:

```
AddCircular(2,-1);
10
AddCircular(10,1);
2
```