# Problem with seeding data in many-to-many relationship. Cannot make migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to seed data in many-to-many relation in my database, but I cannot make a migration. I'm using Entity Framework Core 5.0.6.

Here are my models:

The general idea is: one Tag can belong to many Topics. One Topic can have many Tags.

Tag.cs:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // [...]    

    public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public List<TopicTag> TopicTags { get; set; }
}
```

Topic.cs

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // [...]

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<TopicTag> TopicTags { get; set; }
}
```

And TopicTag.cs

```
public class TopicTag
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public Topic Topic { get; set; }
    
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have in `OnModelCreating` in my `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
// [...]
// Configuring relation
modelBuilder.Entity<Topic>()
    .HasMany(topic => topic.Tags)
    .WithMany(x => x.Topics)
    .UsingEntity<TopicTag>(
        j => j
            .HasOne(tt => tt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.TopicTags)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.TagId),
        j => j
            .HasOne(tt => tt.Topic)
            .WithMany(t => t.TopicTags)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.TopicId),
        j => { j.HasKey(t => new {t.TopicId, t.TagId}); }
    );

modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
    .HasMany(tag => tag.Topics)
    .WithMany(x => x.Tags)
    .UsingEntity<TopicTag>(
        j => j
            .HasOne(tt => tt.Topic)
            .WithMany(t => t.TopicTags)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.TopicId),
        j => j
            .HasOne(tt => tt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.TopicTags)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.TagId),
        j => { j.HasKey(t => new {t.TopicId, t.TagId}); }
    );
// [...]

// Seeding data

for (int t = -1; t >= -4; t--)
{
    builder.Entity<Tag>().HasData(new Tag()
    {
        Id = t,
        Name = "tag" + t
    });
}

for (int y = -1; y >= -10; y--)
{
    builder.Entity<Topic>().HasData(new Topic()
    {
        Id = y,
        // [...]
    });
}

// Finally joining them together
for (int y = -1; y >= -10; y--)
{
    builder.Entity<TopicTag>().HasData(new TopicTag()
    {
        TopicId = y,
        TagId = -1 * ((y % 4) + 1)
    });
}
```

As a result, when I try to create new migration, I receive this error:

> The value of 'TopicTag.TagId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

To be honest, I don't understand the meaning of an error message. `TopicTag.TagId` is known, because I'm specifying it while creating new `TopicTag` in for loop. Moreover, all ids I'm referencing there are created before.

Comment: What db are  you using?

Comment: @Serge MsSQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that you've fallen afoul of a nasty "feature" of C#'s modulo operator.

Let's consider your last loop:

```
/ Finally joining them together
for (int y = -1; y >= -10; y--)
{
    builder.Entity<TopicTag>().HasData(new TopicTag()
    {
        TopicId = y,
        TagId = -1 * ((y % 4) + 1)
    });
}
```

So what happens on the first iteration through the loop?  You may think that `(-1 % 4)` returns something reasonable like 3, but in fact it actually returns -1!  So the whole expression resolves to `-1 * (-1 + 1) == 0` and not -4 which is probably what you wanted.  And since you don't have any tag IDs that are zero, that's where the `TagId is not known` message is coming from.

To address this you can try some of the solutions here: [Mod of negative number is melting my brain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain)

Comment: Quite funny, that was indeed a problem :D Thank you very much