# How do you create a function to wrap numbers to a specified range?

Tags: c#, math, overflow, modulo, underflow

I'm trying to create a function to underflow a number back up or overflow a number back down into a specified range mathematically.  I think I was able to get this to work when the numbers are all positive (taking out `Math.Abs` (used to positivify negative numbers)) but ranges which go negative or negative values fail.  I want to solve this with Maths but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

This is my current implementation of the failing function:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps a value within the specified range, overflowing or underflowing as necessary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The number to wrap.</param>
    /// <param name="minimumValue">The minimum value in the range.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The number of values in the range to wrap across.</param>
    /// <returns>The <paramref name="value"/> wrapped to the specified range.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Thrown if <paramref name="length"/> is <c>0</c>.</exception>
    public static int Wrap(this int value, int minimumValue, int length)
    {
        if (length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(length)} must not be 0 in order to produce a range to wrap across.");
        else
        {
            var absoluteModulus = System.Math.Abs((value - minimumValue) % length);
            
            return (value < 0 ? length - absoluteModulus : absoluteModulus) + minimumValue;
        }
    }
```

Here's some test data and results for the current implementation:

| value | minimumValue | length | expected | actual | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 128 | 256 | 128 | 256 | 256 | Pass |
| 255 | 256 | 256 | 511 | 257 | Modulo is underflowing backwards! |
| -3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | Somehow underflowing out of range! |
| -4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | Again, underflowing out of range! |
| 63 | 128 | 384 | 447 | 193 | 128 - 63 == 65, 384 - 65 == 319, 319 + 128 == 447, not 193‼ |
| 300 | 100 | 200 | 100 | 100 | This overflow works! |

Comment: What about if `length` is less than 0? Is that a case you need to consider?

Comment: That's a nice-to-have but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be aware that `%` is the remainder operation, not [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) (as in modular arithmetic), but simply getting the absolute value of the modulus is not correct. You should use one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1082917/5133585). For example:

```
private static int Mod(int k, int n) {
    int remainder = k % n;
    return (remainder < 0) ? remainder + n : remainder;
}

// ... in the else branch, you can directly do
return Mod(value - minimumValue, length) + minimumValue;
```

You also handled `value < 0` differently. There is nothing special about a negative `value`. What *is* special here, is a negative remainder, which is a value that will never be produced by the modulus operation. Your code would have worked too if you replaced `value < 0` with a check to see if `(value - minimumValue) % length` is negative.