# What is an efficient way to get the least non-negative residue modulo n in C?

Tags: c, math

Is there an efficient way to get the least non-negative residue modulo n, where n is positive, in C?

This is quite easy if the number is non-negative, then it's just a % n (where a is the non-negative integer).

However when a is negative, it appears the behaviour, in C89, is implementation defined (thanks kennyTM). I.e. -2 % 11 = -2 or 9.

Comment: Implementation defined ≠ undefined.

Comment: @nn: The behavior is Implementation defined in C90 but, in C99 the behavior is well defined(the result has the same sign as the sign of the dividend).

Comment: Note that most of the answers given don't actually give the *least* non-negative residue, as they'll give n when a = -n, instead of giving 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739883/how-do-i-find-the-smallest-positive-integer-congruent-to-i-modulo-m

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Furthermore, in C99 the behaviour is defined to be the annoying one: -2 % 11 = -2.

In general (i.e., `n % m` when `m` is not constant and the range of `n` is unconstrained), you probably can't do better than the usual

```
res = ((n % m) + m) % m
```

It may be interesting to compare that to the following on your platform; one branch might win against the extra modulo:

```
res = n % m;
if (res < 0)  res += m;
```

Comment: (nevermind, I was concerned if |n|>m, but it should be fine with the code you specify.)

Comment: The branch will beat the second modulus on almost any current architecture, in almost any circumstance.  Sadly, not very interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I think I last really read anything much about architecture when we had caches and rudimentary pipelines, but branch prediction and such was still a pipedream.  So I internalised a "branches are gonna kill ya" rule of thumb which is now probably at least a decade out of date...

Comment: yeah, for something like this x86 will predict the branch correctly for most reasonable input data distributions, and even the missed branch penalty is cheaper than the modulus operation.  A lot of embedded platforms like ARM will do this without a branch at all (just do a conditional add), so there's no penalty there either.

Answer (score 9):

You could simply check if the result is negative and then act accordingly:

```
int mod(int n, int m) {
   int r = n % m;
   if (r < 0)
      return r + m;
   else
      return r;
}
```

Or, without if-then-else and as a single expression:

```
r = ((n % m) + m) % m;
```

Comment: The if-then-else is likely to be faster as it avoids a division. Bah, I wish I'd seen this before writing my answer. +1.

Comment: @sth Yes, but will this work for numbers like 68^105, 5^18, and 66^75, for example?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (a > 0)
    return a % n;
if (a < 0)
{
    r = n - (-a % n);
    if (r == n)
        return 0;
    return r;
}
```

If a < 0, then `r = -a % n` is a value in [0, n) such that k * n + r = -a for some integer k. 
Then n - r is a value in (0, n], and since -r = a + k * n, we have n - r = a + (k + 1) * n, or a = (n - r) + (-k - 1) * n. From this you can see that n - r is the modulus of a, and since it is in (0, n], it is non-negative.

Finally, you want the result to be in the range [0, n), not in (0, n]. To ensure this, we check if r is n, and if so, return 0. (Which is of course modulus-n-equivalent to n)

Answer (score 0):

Few processors implement remainder in hardware, rather it's synthesized from a division and a multiplication. So this is not really a cumbersome reimplementation from the machine's standpoint:

```
int qm = n / m * m; // a positive or negative multiple of m, rounded up or down
if ( qm <= n ) return n - qm; // usual definition of %
else return n - qm + m; // most common definition of -%, with adjustment
```

Micro-optimization of the conditional `+` may also be beneficial. This could be faster or slower on your machine, but it will work:

```
int rem = n - n / m * m;
return rem + m & -( rem < 0 );
```

Total cost: one regular modulo plus one right-shift (to generate `-(rem<0)`), one bitwise and, and one add.