# Least Non-Negative Residue: Large Numbers

Tags: c++, primes, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to build a C++ program that can solve the modular congruence:

> n^p = x (mod q ),

where n is a small number, and p and q are very large arbitrary primes. I've tried to do this multiple times, but I always run into memory overflow issues. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show your source code?

Comment: Maybe. I can check to see if it still decipherable. It will take a sec though because I'm running Windows Server in parallel on a Mac.

Comment: I say "decipherable" because where the code is stored is but one of many blocks of unrelated code all commented out in main. This is because it is just a test .cpp file, so I have a bunch of commented out programs all in one .cpp file. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. It would help if you could simplify as much as possible before presenting here.

Comment: When I say large number I mean something like 94^1355894606365957843469521488463510701121587912991797864784158488712181744589731257712176047767743727.

Comment: Is that even possible?

Comment: Damn. It seems as though I overwrote the test.cpp file. The only thing there is an empty function body.

Comment: Do you not use [version control](http://hginit.com/)? Does your editor not store backups, or editing history?

Comment: yes, although you would likely need a library that would cope with numbers of that size,

Comment: @suspectus What do you mean? What library?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2012. You are saying there is a way to recover it? How? No, I don't use this "version control" you speak of.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh integers won't go that big without some help. You need a [Big Number library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c).

Comment: So use #include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh", then?

Comment: How do I implement it?

Comment: While I half-suspect that this is a wind-up, some interpretations of it could be solved, in principle.  My most immediate question is this: which of n, p, x and q are known, and which do you need the program to find?  Without this clarification, calls for source code are probably premature.

Comment: What is a wind-up? n, p, and q are all known (privately using a some method or broadcast); however, x is not known. I need a way to find this x given these three knowns and the congruence.

Comment: What about these people's [ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708851/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-get-the-least-non-negative-residue-modulo-n-in-c)?

Comment: Just as and aside, does anybody here know of a decent random character scrambler?

Comment: A wind-up is a 'silly question' asked because it has no good answers.  Finding x is easy - it is (n*p)%q - but you need to evaluate that with a suitable data-type.  I recommend reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic  There are suitable libraries for C/C++ but none are "easy" to use.  You can do this in one line of Python.

Comment: OK, so I know that n can be at most a certain integer, say e, so then I must ensure that e*p<=18,446,744,073,709,551,615, right?

Comment: I'm not looking for "easy" Mr. aSteve.

Comment: This just all smells like OP is fishing for somebody to do the work for him

Comment: @MrBarukh, in that case, use GMP or MPIR http://www.mpir.org/ (or an alternative of your choice) and evaluate (n*p)%q.  If only x is unknown, your only difficulty is that C++ has no native support for "large" integers.

Comment: @MrBarukh (P.S. Sorry, I had misread n^p as n*p - my mistake.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple algorithm for *b* ^ *e* (mod *m*):

```
function powerMod(b, e, m)
    x := 1
    while e > 0
        if e % 2 == 1
            x := (b * x) % m
        b := (b * b) % m
        e := e // 2 # integer division
    return x
```

You should *not* calculate *b* ^ *e* and then perform the modulo operation, as the intermediate number will be huge. I'll leave it to you to translate to your preferred language with datatypes suitable for storing the large numbers you need. I discuss this algorithm at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/07/07/modular-arithmetic/).

Comment: What do you mean by `e := e // 2 # integer division`?

Comment: unsigned long long powerMod( unsigned long long b , unsigned long long e , unsigned long long m )
{
 int x = 1;
 while( e > 0 )
 {
  if( e % 2 == 1 )
  {
   x = ( b*x ) % m;
  }
  b = ( b*b) % m;
  e = e

Comment: This will run for quite some time won't it?

Comment: Integer division ignores remainders; thus e // 2 (where the double-slash indicates integer division) is the same as floor(e / 2). The runtime is O(log2 e), which is quite fast. See the Wikipedia page for Modular Exponentiation for details.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comments on your question, it sounds like you are trying to shove very large values into variables that can't hold values that large.

Look here for more information about data types and the ranges they can hold:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.110).aspx

The largest data type range I found with non negative numbers is `unsigned long long`. It holds a range of values from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Comment: Will that number be the same on my system though?

Comment: This is the maximum value for an unsigned 64bit integer. (0xffffffffffffffff) which equals 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Those values are true on Visual Studio 2012. So to answer your question, you will not be able to use big numbers like you want to without help from a library of some sort like the Big Number Library that Peter Wood mentioned in the comment section to your question post. If using that solves your problem, please make sure to upvote his comment.

Comment: Did you see Peter Wood's comment?