# obtaining two large numbers and reducing their difference by taking their mod values iteratively in C

Tags: c, algorithm, math, modulus

Well, let us say i am supposed to obtain D = (A - B) mod M, where A and B are very large, large as in, long long wont help. A and B were obtained iteratively and independently and i would obtain A mod M at each iteration and B mod M at each iteration. Now, let us say B is always smaller than A, but (B mod M) can be larger than (A mod M), then when D is evaluated, a negative number will be obtained, which isnt right, because, well, B is smaller than A. How do I go about this? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to get the least non-negative residue modulo n in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708851/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-get-the-least-non-negative-residue-modulo-n-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `((A mod M) - (B mod M)) mod M` gives you a negative result (as it may, since older C leaves the result of modulus implementation-defined when either argument is negative, and C99 defines it so that the result is negative if the dividend is negative), simply add `M` to get the result you want. After all, x and x+M are equivalent, mod M.