# Java modular inverse

Tags: java, modulo, inverse

I'm doing some error correction in Java and to cut a long story short;

Under mod 11:

```
-4 mod 11 = 7
```

This I've confirmed by using Google's calculator and a couple of online modulo calculators, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it in Java.

I'm thinking that I need to use an inverse table to find the correct number but I seem to be going round in circles.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thank in advance

Tony

Comment: This is not a modular inverse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will compute `n mod 11` for any integer `n`:

```
(n % 11 + 11) % 11
```

The result of `n % 11` is in the range `-10`...`10`. The subsequent addition and the second modulo operation add `11` to `n % 11` iff the latter is negative.

This formula works for any base: just replace `11` with another positive integer.

Comment: Or in general for `n` mod `y`: `(n % y + y) % y`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  That was driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 3):

It'd be pretty simple to just write a mod function which does what you require. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java/2172061#2172061):

```
private int mod(int x, int y)
{
    int result = x % y;
    if (result < 0)
    {
        result += y;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's much clearer than using `% 11 + 11) % 11`, and the operation makes sense immediately when you look at it. `mod(32, 11)` is more clearly `32 mod 11` than `(32 % 11 + 11) % 11`, and it saves an extra `%` operation.

Comment: ... and it costs an extra test and branch.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989943/weird-objective-c-mod-behavior/990007#990007) answer and comments on it provide my reasoning. Mod is likely a more expensive CPU operation compared to a test and branch. It may not even end up branching.

Comment: Yes, I read it. I guess I will never understand why computer programmers are so terrified of arithmetic, given that formula translation is how it all started.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Language Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/jTOC.doc.html), Java's `%` operator [is a remainder operator, not a modulo operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#24956).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you take the positive modulo (4 mod 11) and subtract from the latter value it should give you the right answer every time. (i.e. 11 - (4 mod 11) = 7) I haven't really gone through and tested it but it seems to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BigInteger#mod](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod%28java.math.BigInteger%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have a method that can calculate the mode inverse of a. TC O(logm) SC O(logm). We are using the Euclid algorithm: “a and m are co-primes if GCD(a,m) == 1”. Please use the link below.

[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72922841/5475941)