# Remainder of float division

Tags: objective-c

How do I compute the remainder of the division of two `float`s?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989943/weird-objective-c-mod-behavior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `a-floor(a/b)*b` - presuming `a` and `b` both positive?

You could say that "remainder" is not a proper concept for float divisions, but I'll leave that to your own judgment.

Comment: I keep getting value of `0.2` for `99.6` and `0.2` - though it should be 0 of course just as `996%2` is 0.

Answer (score 28):

Use `fmod`, which computes the floating point modulus.

```
double remainder = fmod(a_double, another_double);
```

If you want to use `float` instead of `double` you'd use `fmodf` instead.

Comment: `fmod( 97.2, 0.2 )` returns `0.2`, that's not very useful.

Comment: @TomášZato The problem here is that neither 97.2 nor 0.2 can be represented _exactly_ as floating point numbers. See [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate). In my debugger, I get `97.200000000000002` and `0.20000000000000001` as arguments, with the result being `0.19999999999999746`. You might need a fixed point math library for your case.

Comment: I guess this also explains why doing `if( remainder==0 || remainder==another_double)` failed too, as `0.19999999999999746` does not equal `0.2`. I will compare difference between numbers than.

Comment: This will not work for negative values as modulo does not really return the remainder. (It does in math, but not in C) Even though this is the more common solution, the accepted answer will work for all values, this will get you in trouble down the road. Of course it's a much easier route if you know all values will be > 0.

Comment: `(-1)%4` is 3 for example, but in Obj-C you will get an answer of negative one. This happens with `fmod()` too. It's a shame imo.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: That's not true. Try it in C: `printf("%d, %f\n", -1 % 4, fmod(-1, 4));` yields `-1, -1.000000`. If your language of choice is yielding a different result for negative numbers, see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) why.

Comment: What I've said is that C will yield -1 which is incorrect. (-1)%4 is actually "3", not "-1". http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%254

Comment: How can the remainder of any divisor be negative? Modulo does not produce the remained in C for negative inputs; it produces some other value. -1 is not the remainder of -1/4, 3 is.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: Read the [Wikipedia on Remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder): the _absolute remainder_ may be negative. The fact that the result is against your intuition doesn't make it incorrect.

Comment: You're referring to the *least absolute remainder* which is something different than the *remainder* in maths. I'm not saying it's incorrect—I'm simply warning future readers that fmod does not return the remainder, it returns the modulus.